# Power Automate: Change order of input fields of "For a selected file" SharePoint trigger

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow. it has a SharePoint trigger of type "For a selected file". I have several input fields in that trigger. I want to change the order of those fields. how can I do that?
[image]

Comment: You can't just delete them and put them back in the order you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are not settings/options available to change the order of inputs added to Power Automate flow triggers.

So, you will have to delete the existing inputs and create new inputs in the correct order.

[image]

---

Above solution is an easy solution and using the browsers only. You can also try below workaround in cases where you have lot of inputs added to Power Automate trigger:

1. Export your flow as zip package
2. Extract the zip file contents
3. Open `definition.json` file from nested folder (Microsoft flow --> flows --> `<flow-guid>` --> `definition.json`)
4. Find the triggers > inputs > properties section and change the order of properties. For example:

   [image]
5. Save this file and create zip file again from all folder contents
6. Import the zip package and create new flow

Here is the output:

[image]

**Reference**: [Export and import your flows across environments with packaging](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/import-export-bap-packages/)